# Nesting Tags In CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I am trying to get a image to display in a hidden area, this is a section of code I have copied from another page that someone else made. So it all works, you click the button and the hidden area appears and I can get data from the table I made to display and change the css around that, no problem.

```
$tmp .= $html->tag('span',$html->tag('h3',
```

The complete code is below, but the line above is where I am working. This Is the start of the hidden area. What I would like to do is have the img image tag inside the span tag. However all my code does, at this time, is to print/echo the location I have put in the database but not display the image. I am not sure if this is something I have done wrong with where I have put the file, webroot/img/events/tempimg.jpg, what is does print is 'img/events/tempimg.jpg'. From that I take it my image is in the right place just that I have opened the tags in the wrong way. Or would it be better to close the span tag 1st this open the img tag, if so how would I make sure it only appears in the hidden area and not on the main page.

```
        $tmp = $html->tag('strong', $NewDate. " - " . $EventTitle.'<br />');  
                    $tmp .= $html->tag('div', substr($EventLoc, 0, 10).'... <br />', array('class' => 'EventInfo'));

                    $tmp .= $html->tag('span',$html->tag('h3',
                        __d('EventsHeader', $e['Team']['name'] . ' Events ', true), array('class' => 'EventInfos'))
                        .$html->tag('img', $EventImage, array('class' => 'EventHide hide'))
                        .nl2br($EventInfo . ' testing more......'), array('class' => 'EventHide hide')
                    );
```

Many Thanks for any help

Glenn Curtis.

Comment: Personally I would think the HTML helper is overkill for this, it would be much, much clearer to write the HTML out yourself and just echo the variables as you need them.

Comment: Thanks For the fast reply, yes I could do that, but the guy who set the 1st page up used the HTML helper tag. Is it not faster for CakePHP to progress the command using this tag? Or does it not really matter?

Comment: It's always going to be fast to spit out static HTML then it is to parse a PHP function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case this helps anyone else, this is now I have now built the tag up, with not using the HTML helper

```
                $tmp .= "<div class=\"EventHide hide\">
                                <h3 class=\"EventInfos\">" .$e['Team']['name'] . " Events - ". $EventTitle ." - ". $EventLoc ."</h3>
                                <div class=\"\"><img src=\"$EventImage\" width=\"250\" height=\"200\"/></div>
                                <span class=\"EventDisplayDate\">When : $DisplayDate</span>
                                <span class=\"EventDisplayLoc\">Where : $EventLoc</span>
                                <span class=\"EventDisplayDes\">Description<br/>$EventInfo</span>
                            </div>";
```

Glenn.